# How to reverse a string without effecting the numbers in R?

Tags: r, string, reverse

I want to reverse a string but without affecting the numbers.
For example:

input: "abcdef 123"
output: "fedcba 123"

at the moment I use this function I found here but it affects all the characters:

```
name<-sapply(strsplit(name, split = ""),
           function(str) {paste(rev(str), collapse = "")})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust solution:

```
# convert vector of strings into list of vectors of words
words = strsplit(name, ' ', fixed = TRUE)

str_rev = sapply(words, function(x) {
  # we know some warnings may be created, ignore them
  suppressWarnings({
    is_num = !is.na(as.numeric(x))
  })

  # reverse non-numeric elements
  str_words = strsplit(x[!is_num], "", fixed = TRUE)
  x[!is_num] = sapply(str_words, function(y) {
    paste(rev(y), collapse = "")
  })
  paste(x, collapse = ' ')
})
```

This allows the rule to be applied in more general cases where you don't know where the numeric "word" will appear and to `name` as a vector:

```
name = c("abcdef 123", 'abc def 123', 'abc 123 def')
str_rev
# [1] "fedcba 123"  "cba fed 123" "cba 123 fed"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option that makes use of `stri_reverse` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("([^0-9 ]+)", ~ stri_reverse(x), name)
#[1] "fedcba 123"  "cba fed 123" "cba 123 fed"
```

Or as @G. Grothendieck mentioned, the anonymous function call can be removed

```
gsubfn("([^0-9 ]+)", stri_reverse, name)
```

#### data

```
name <- c("abcdef 123", 'abc def 123', 'abc 123 def')
```

Comment: Small point but note that the second argument could be shortened: `gsubfn("([^0-9 ]+)", stri_reverse, name)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

**Case 1:**

```
a <- "abcdef 123"

# split the string
split_a <- unlist(strsplit(a, " "))

# reverse it
paste(paste(rev(strsplit(split_a[1],'')[[1]]), collapse = ''), split_a[2])

"fedcba 123"
```

**Case 2:**

```
a <- "abc def 123"

# split the string
split_a <- unlist(strsplit(a, " "))

# removing the last word
to_split <- split_a[-length(split_a)]

reversed <- paste(sapply(lapply(strsplit(to_split, NULL), rev), paste, collapse=''), collapse=' ')

final <- paste(reversed, split_a[length(split_a)], collapse=" ")

[1] "cba fed 123"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but do you have an idea of making it work with strings containing more than two words?

Comment: @DanBoguslavsky example ?

Comment: input: abc def 123
output: cba fed 123

Comment: @DanBoguslavsky yes, adding it in a while.

Comment: It seems to work most of the time but @MichaelChirico is really more reliable whereas the location of the numeric word, though I gave the specific example so it's my bad too.
Thanks a lot anyway. really appreciate it!

Comment: I believe that too. I also learned something from his approach.